# Mongoose OR operator for schema definitions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Does Mongoose support, or is there an available package that supports multiple "options" for the embedded schemas in an array?

For example, the **things** property can contain only one of two schemas:

```
new Schema({
    things: [{
        requiredProp: String,
        otherProp: Number
    }, {
        otherOption: Number
    }]
});
```

In other words, I do not want to just allow **anything** (AKA Schema.Types.Mixed) to be stored in this property, but only these two possible definitions.

Or, do schema design recommendations exist to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only define one dict in the array type of the schema, and then set if they are required or not with the mongoose schema types logic. Use pre save if you want to do more logic to assure that either one of the fields have been set, like this:

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
    things: [{
        requiredProp: {type: String, required: true},
        otherProp: Number,
        otherOption: Number,
    }]
});

MySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (!this.otherProp && !this.otherOption) {
        next(new Error('Both otherProp and otherOption can\'t be null'))
    } else {
        next()
    }
})
```

Opon saving the object it will return an error if neither otherProp nor otherOption has been set.